# Infinite Loop on Get_Next_Line in C

Tags: c, string

I have to create a C function that returns a line read from a file descriptor. I have to define a macro `READ_SIZE` (that can be editable). This `READ_SIZE` indicates the number of characters to read at each call of `read()`. The number can only be positive.

I also have to use one or several static variables to save the characters that were read but not sent back to the calling function. One .C file (5 functions max, 25 lines max per function) and one .h file only.

My function `Get_Next_Line` shall return its return without the '\n'. If there is nothing more to read on the file descriptor, or if an error occur while reading, the function returns NULL.

Here is the prototype of the function:

```
char *get_next_line(const int fd)

FUNCTIONS ALLOWED: malloc, free, read, write (to use with my_putchar, my_putstr, etc).
```

Here is what I have, but it doesn't work. It does an infinite loop I am trying to know why.

```
char        *my_strcat(char *str1, char *str2)
{
  int       i;
  int       j;
  int       s;
  char      *strfinal;

  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  s = 0;
  if ((strfinal = malloc(sizeof(char) * (my_strlen(str1) + my_strlen(str2) 
                      + 1))) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  while (str1[i] != '\0')
    {
      strfinal[j] = str1[i];
      i++;
      j++;
    }
  while (str2[s] != '\0')
    {
      strfinal[j] = str2[s];
      s++;
      j++;
    }
  free(str1);
  strfinal[j] = '\0';
  return (strfinal);
}

char        *get_next_line(const int fd)
{
  int       n;
  int       i;
  char      *str_to_return;
  static char   buff[READ_SIZE] = {'\0'};

  n = 1;
  i = 0;
  str_to_return = NULL;
  while (n)
  {
    if (i == 0 && buff == '\0')
    {
      if ((read(fd, buff, READ_SIZE)) <= 0)
        return(str_to_return);
      if (i == READ_SIZE - 1 || buff[i] == '\n')
      {
          n = 0;
          str_to_return = my_strcat(buff, str_to_return);
          i = -1;
      }
    }
    i++;
  }
  printf("%s\n", str_to_return);
  return (str_to_return);
}
```

Comment: `.C` is normally used for C++. use `.c` for C code.

Comment: using for loops would make this much easier for you and us.

Comment: as would using variable names longer than one letter.

Comment: `free(str1);` is attempting to free `buff[]` which is a static variable.

Comment: `if (i == 0 && buff == '\0')` is a syntax error. You cannot compare an array with a character. Do you have compiler warnings enabled?

Comment: @Someone my school forbide me to use for loops unfortunately.

Comment: @interjay I will try to use longer names for my variables in the future, thanks ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane I wanted to say that IF my buff is full of '\0'. Working on that!

Comment: "my school forbide me to use for loops unfortunately" is not an expected restriction in coding.  Better to post all such restrictions in the post rather than mentioning them one at a time in the comments

Comment: "my school forbide me to use for loops unfortunately"  --> then why code `while()` loops?

Comment: @chux sorry, I forgot to add it in the main post, my bad. Well, we have to code while() loops to avoid for loops and to learn how for loops work. That's my school's pedagogy, can't do nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

in this code:

```
while (str1[i] != '\0')
{
   strfinal[j] = str1[i];
   i++;
   j++;
}
```

what guarantee do you have that there will be the null character `\0` somewhere in `str1[]`  ???

same goes for the str2 while loop.
If no null character is encountered, then there will be an infinite loop there.

verify the functions you are using to populate characters into memory under `str1[]` and `str2[]` include the null character.  Since you are only using the `read()` function prior then that answer is no.

The problem with your two while loops for `str1[]` and `str2[]` is that you are relying on the null character to already be there in memory.  And that then begs the question, who put that data there in memory and were they given a requirement to terminate the character data with a null character?
you therefore need to somehow place a control over any loop you write so as not get caught in an infinite loop condition; in this case maybe use a counter and after so many advances of the `i` to access `str1[i]` then stop, because you have yet to see a null character.

for example, the `fgets()` function will read so many characters from a FILE stream into an array, and always terminate it with the null character.

Comment: The infinite loop is in the 2nd function (get_last_line())... *strcat* assumes the string of chars it points to has a tailing 0, so it is fair that *my_strcat* assumes the same.

Comment: yeah i can see in the 2nd function called get_next_line()  the problem.  The while (n) loop which has one big if statement followed by i++;    after the first interation i is incremented from zero and the condition to enter the if statement is never met.  therefore the value of n never changes resulting in infinite loop with i++ happening forever.  that section needs to be fixed before anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i == 0 && buff == '\0')
```

is always false because your definition of buff is

```
static char   buff[READ_SIZE] = {'\0'};
```

You are attempting to test if buff is empty when i is 0. However as a char pointer, buff is an address and is never 0. You mean to make the if

```
if (i == 0 && buff[0] == '\0')
```

in order to check if the first character is the Null character.

However, once i is incremented, then it always fails even if you test against

```
if (i == 0 && buff[i] == '\0')
```

in order to find the NULL character within the buffer. Since you enter the while with i = 0 and are checking if buff is empty, you do not need the while.

If you want to just fill the buffer and keep reading until it is full, you need a different type of test. You also need a way of checking if you need to exit the while loop if the if fails (put in an else to determine what to do).

You also do not need to check each character in buff against '\0' because your code has always insured that it ends with one (even for initialization). Thus, strlen(buff) would be valid.

Another point is that when you call mystrcat() you have already verified that buffer is empty.

Also, since the second string in the call is what you read in, then the mystrcat() will not always have a '\0' at the end of str2 (though you are guaranteeing that buff (str1) will). You should call it with the number of characters in str2 to use.